# Pass Ctrl + Click Event to another element in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

It's come to my understanding that Firefox will not pass Ctrl + Click from label, to target input field. I'm at a loss as to how I can achieve this behaviour. I have checkbox fields, which are hidden, and their respective labels that are styled uniquely and visible... When clicking the label, click registers, but control click does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume html as

```
<form>
 <label for="home" id="lblhome">home</label>
 <input type="checkbox" name="home" id="home"><br>
</form>
```

I want one thing if ctrl+cliked other thing if it's just click , the checkbox click code

```
$( "#home" ).click( function( e) {
if(e.ctrlKey)
  alert('i just got ctrl+cliked');
else
 alert('i just got clicked');
});
```

So now create handler for label check if it's ctrl+click if yes then create an jquery Event and change its **ctrlKey** property to true and **trigger** it on the checkbox.

```
$('#lblhome').click(
function(e){
  if(e.ctrlKey) {
    alert('ctrl+click on label');

    //cancel the normal click 
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    e2 = jQuery.Event("click");        
    //e2.which = 50;        //   for other key combos like CTRL+A+click 
    e2.ctrlKey = true;
    $( "#home").triggerHandler(e2);
    $( "#home").prop("checked", !$( "#home").prop("checked"));//toggle checkbox state
   }
});
```

DEMO : https://jsfiddle.net/35g41aaL/

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of hacky, but it works: http://jsbin.com/dogelehena/edit?html,console,output

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cb">
<label for="cb">Label</label>

<script>
$(function () {
  var cb = $('#cb');
  var isFirefox = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1;

  $('label').click(function (e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey && isFirefox) {
      var checked = cb.prop('checked');
      cb.prop('checked', !checked);
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

First, attaching the `click` event to the `label` and not the `input`. This way, the event is not blocked when ctrl is held down, but the checkbox state does not change. So in the callback, we check for `e.ctrlKey`, and if it's true, we change that checkbox's state manually.

Please note that I added the `isFirefox` check, because while this functionality fixes the behavior in Firefox, it breaks in other browsers.

Comment: Close to what I needed, but not exactly, +1 for the useful info though. I will keep this in mind.